# overridePendingTransition in Android SDK doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

I'm trying to get change the transition between two activities in an Android application. I found that overridePendingTransition would do the job, but it doesn't seem to work for me.
This is the code I'm working with:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);

  ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
  Animation fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

  fade.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

   @Override
   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    startActivity(new Intent(FDSplashActivity.this,
      FDGameActivity.class));
    FDSplashActivity.this.finish();
          overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
   }

  });
  logo.startAnimation(fade);
}
```

It's supposed to show the splash screen, fade in a logo and then switch to another activity. That works, but not the line overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);.
When I'm hovering it in Eclipse it just says: "The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type new Animation.AnimationListener(){}"

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

overridePendingTransition is a method of Activity. Just as you have done for the call to finish(), try using

```
FDSplashActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. But I replaced the line with yours and I'm still getting a red line under the word overridePendingTransition. What am I doing wrong? Am I using the wrong SDK version?

Comment: I was. Eclipse had automatically picked Android 1.6 as the Project Build Target. But after changing to 2.1 instead, it now works great. Thanks man!

Comment: inside a fragment, use it like `getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);`