# how to overridePendingTransition(int, int) in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, animation

I've got a button in a class ActivityMain which extends FragmentActivity.
When the button is pressed I would like to animate the next activity in.
tried:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" 
            + appPackageName)));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
```

Error I am receiving:

```
"The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined 
for the type ActivityMain"
```

How can I animate the next activity?

Comment: try `ActivtyName.this.overridePendingTran..`

Comment: Doesn't work trying to trick it to (Activity)

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code. It should actually work the way you're describing it, so there has to be some error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: you dont have to trick it to an activity, a fragment activity extends an activity. try cleaning your project or else post your method

Comment: change your sdk version to 2.1 may be or even 2.0 @JY2k

Comment: Changed to 2.2 And it worked. post it as answer and I will flag correct.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! @JY2k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined 
for the type ActivityMain
```

The above takes place because the method is not defined for the fragmentActivity in the sdkVersion mentioned.

Change the sdk verstion to 2.0 or 2.1 and it will work.

Picked from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844629/overridependingtransition-in-android-sdk-doesnt-work)

> ```
> I was. Eclipse had automatically picked Android 1.6 as the Project Build Target.
> ```
>
> But after changing to 2.1 instead, it now works great.
>   Thanks man! –  Daniel Jonsson Jan 30 '11 at 20:07